# How to convert number words to integers in Postgres (IE 'four' to '4')

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to convert words like "fifteen" to "15" in postgres rather than writing a big case statement? I need it to accomodate 1-50.

Comment: Join to a mapping table.

Comment: Sounds like something you could find in text-to-speech code repositories. Quick search returned lots of solution to the [opposite problem](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Integer_to_Text) which are still [useful to generate a map](https://dbfiddle.uk/CQ-BP8Iw).

Comment: you can store the mapping in a dedicated table with 2 columns and create a function with an input parameter of type int and an output parameter of type text that returns the corresponding word of the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :

1. Store the mapping values in a dedicated table with 1 column of type integer (or even serial) and 1 column of type text
2. Create a function which will retrieve the corresponding text for a given number

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kj7JQC1H)

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I rewrote it to do text to number.  Thank you! https://dbfiddle.uk/vrCcir34

Answer (score 1):

You can trick [monetary type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html) function `cash_words()` into doing something like that, as long as you can deal with the currency-related words and precision:

```sql
create or replace function read_number(num numeric) 
  returns text language sql immutable strict as $$
SELECT  
    lower(
        trim(
            replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    cash_words(num::money),
                    ' dollar.*',--cut out currency and fractions
                    ''
                ),
                '  ',--remove accidental double spaces
                ' ' 
            )
        )
    )
$$;

drop table if exists number_readings;
create table number_readings as 
  select num,read_number(num) as num_reading
from generate_series(0,2e5,1) as a(num);

create index on number_readings (num_reading) 
  include (num) with (fillfactor=100);
```

And then:

```sql
create or replace function text_to_num(txt text)
  returns int language sql immutable strict as $$
select num*(case when lower(txt) ~ '^minus.*' then -1 else 1 end)
from number_readings 
where num_reading=trim(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                lower(txt),
                                ' and',
                                ''),
                            '-',
                            ' '),
                        'minus ',
                        '')
                    )
$$;

select text_to_num('one hundred fifty six thousand seven hundred forty two');
 text_to_num
-------------
      156742

select text_to_num('Minus One hundred and fifty-six thousand seven hundred');
 text_to_num
-------------
     -156700
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oqZlbOPB)